# How to NuxtLink with Dynamic, Nested Pages?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxtjs2

I have a URL that looks like this where _websiteId and _appId is UUID:

`/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/plugins`

how can I link between the above and:

`/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/settings`

without losing:

`/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/`

and without ending up with:

`/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/plugins/settings`

using NuxtLinks?

Comment: can you show your code and what you have tried ? nuxt links can point to any url in your app, doesn't need to be relative

Comment: Can you explain more? How do you get the dynamic ids, is it from an API? If so, can you give us an insight/example of the API data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have dynamic routes set up with the two params `_websiteId` and `_appId` to handle your URL format:

```
/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/settings
/websites/_websiteId/apps/_appId/plugins
```

You can access the params from route using Composition API and reconstruct the URL based on your need:

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()

const websiteId = route.params._websiteId
const appId = route.params._appId
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLink :to="`/websites/${websiteId}/apps/${appId}/settings`">
      Settings
    </NuxtLink>
    <NuxtLink :to="`/websites/${websiteId}/apps/${appId}/plugins`">
      Plugins
    </NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Example of the corresponding pages directory:
[image]

More info on pages structure and dynamic route params https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#example